# how to overwrite a file after confirmation during upload in php

Tags: php, file-upload, overwrite

I am trying to upload and overwrite a file after submit when checked if file already exists.
So if first check if a file already exists in a folder, and then i will give the option: "Dow you want to overwrite it?" If YES, the file should be uploaded and overwrite the old one.

This is what i have so far:

```
...
// file is ready to be uploaded    
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];            
$newFilePath = $dir.'/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];

// check if file already exists
if(file_exists($dir.'/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
        include('includes/file_exists.php');
        exit;
 }

 //finally upload the file
 if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {    
    include('includes/success.php'); // echo                
    exit;                                   
 }
```

In `file_exists.php` is this code:

```
<span>File already exists! Do you want to overwrite it?</span>
<form class="sfmform"  action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="overwrite" value="<?php echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; ?>" />                             
    <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary" name="submitoverwrite" value="Yes"/>
</form>
```

(all requests are handled by AJAX)

Comment: Why the`exit()`?

Comment: i dynamically reload the page; otherwise some things are outputted twice

Comment: That is still not good enough reason for exit. You shouldn't kill the script because you don't know how to control it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file already exists, what you'll have to do is move the uploaded file to a temporary location (can't leave it in tmp because it'll get deleted) and return a response that tells the UI that you need confirmation to overwrite (or ask for a new name). When the user decides, the UI has to send a new request to the server. When you handle this new request, you move the file to the final location.

Comment: So if i understand correctly: if file exists, DO upload the file to a `tmp` folder. After the confirmation request, move the file from the `tmp` folder to its final destination? Sounds very logic..

Comment: Correct. You can't leave the file in it's original temporary location because the system will delete it automatically.